# Google One Tap Login not Working in chrome incognito

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-oauth

I am working on adding one tap login to my project using google [JS api](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference), code for the same

```
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
        callback: LoginSuccess,
        prompt_parent_id: "root",
        itp_support: true,      
    });
```

This is working fine firefox, safari in both normal and incognito mode, but in chrome its working fine in normal but not working in incognito mode (Allowed all the cookies in incognito), it returning response as `opt_out_or_no_session`.

i tried with setting the `g_state` cookie, but it doesn’t not work

```
google.accounts.id.prompt(function(oneTapPromptResponse) {
    if (oneTapPromptResponse.isNotDisplayed()) {
        document.cookie =  "g_state=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT";
        console.info("Google Login Not Displayed");
    } else if (oneTapPromptResponse.isSkippedMoment()) {
        console.info("Google Login skiiped");
    } else if (oneTapPromptResponse.isDismissedMoment()) {
        console.info("Google Login dismissed");
    } else if (oneTapPromptResponse.isDisplayed()) {
        console.info("Google Login displayed")
    }
});
```

Attached the image for Firefox private browsing mode response

[image: Firefox private browsing mode response]

Can anyone help me to resolve this.